# GitPython Is it possible to get file from specified commit without checkout

Tags: python, gitpython

I want to copy files from specified commit with GitPython. Now I come here so far:

```
import git
git = git.Git(REPO_PATH)
git.checkout(COMMIT_HEX_SHA)
fo = open(REPO_PATH + "/foo.txt", "r")
str = fo.read(10);
fo.close()
```

It works. But `checkout` changes `HEAD` and changes files. Is it possible to copy files or read files from specified commit without `checkout`?

Comment: It should be possible to use obtain a blob from any commit and read from it, e.g. `git.Repo().commit(COMMIT_HEX_SHA).tree['subdir/somefile.ext'].data_stream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Byron's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33853337/241211#comment56023523_33853337) does indeed give you a stream, but a word of caution: If you're used to using a `with`-`as` construct or `.readlines()` to read streams, don't try them here. Go for plain `.read()`.

```py
git.Repo().commit(COMMIT_HEX_SHA).tree['subdir/somefile.ext'].data_stream.read()
```

If you don't want the trailing newline, you can also delegate directly to `git show` like [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511659/241211):

```py
git.Repo().git.show(f'{COMMIT_HEX_SHA}:{file_with_path}')
```